# Remote into a computer with PowerShell

Tags: windows, networking, command-line, powershell, remote-access

I am trying to remote into a computer via PowerShell, but I get this error:

```
WinRM client cannot process the request. If the authentication scheme is different from
Kerberos, or if the client computer is not joined to a domain, then HTTPS transport must be
used or the destination machine must be added to the TrustedHosts configuration setting. Use
winrm.cmd to configure TrustedHosts. Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not
be authenticated. You can get more information about that by running the following command:
winrm help config. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At line:1 char:1
+ etsn <ip address here> -Credential '<username here>'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (<ip address here>:String) [Enter-PSSession], PSRemoti
   ngTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed
```

I tried adding my computer to trusted hosts, but I keep getting this error. How can I remote into another computer via PowerShell?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to run Enable-PSRemoting on the remote machine.  Also, insure the Remote Registry service is running on the remote machine too.

Comment: I tried that, and WinRM was already configured. I’m still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you try to add both the computer name and the IP to the trusted hosts?  Other than that you can also set the local group policy to allow unencrypted connections under WinRM cleint.

Comment: Tried that too. I'm still getting the exact same error. Do I need to be on the same domain or workgroup?